# Flutter ${widget.name} into TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

is there any way to put ${widget.name} to hintText inside TextFormField?
It works fine with other Texts widgets, but inside hintText i've got an error

```
           Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                enabled: false,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Name: ${widget.name}',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.done)),
              ),
            ),
```

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5E36.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your screenshot says "Invalid constant value" in the last line. It should work if you remove the "const" from your InputDecoration.

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: TextFormField(
    enabled: false,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'Name: ${widget.name}',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.done)),
    ),
),
```